# Error while deploying a web application in OSGI container using pax web

Tags: jetty, osgi, apache-felix, pax

Hello I am trying to deploy a web application in a Felix container.
I have all the required configuration done with my web app like the setting up of the manifest headers:
Webapp-Context:
Bundle-ClassPath:
Bundle-Activator: 
Import-Package:
Bundle-SymbolicName:
etc
The Pax bundles that I have dropped in the same container are:
pax-web-service-0.6.0.jar
pax-web-jsp-0.7.1.jar
pax-web-extender-war-0.7.1.jar
pax-logging-service-1.5.0.jar
pax-logging-api-1.5.0.jar

Though it had been written in the pax web site that pax-web-service is included in pax-war-extender, it seems without pax-web-service bundle, all other bundles become handicapped.

I had removed the other pax bundles like 
pax-web-extender-whiteboard-0.7.1.jar
pax-web-jetty-0.7.1.jar, as I have not seen any usefulness of those.

The pax-web-jetty-0.7.1.jar even does not get start up. it has dependencies which it could not be able to resolve from any one of the bundle provided by PAX.

My browser is displaying:
HTTP ERROR 403

Problem accessing /adminmodule/. Reason:

FORBIDDEN

Powered by Jetty://

---

### while the Console log says:

[5884890@qtp-16567002-0 - /adminmodule/] DEBUG org.mortbay.jetty - REQUEST /adminmodule/ on org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection@1e94001
[5884890@qtp-16567002-0 - /adminmodule/] DEBUG org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.model.ServerModel - Matching [/adminmodule/]...
[5884890@qtp-16567002-0 - /adminmodule/] DEBUG org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.model.ServerModel - Path [/adminmodule/] matched to {pattern=/adminmodule/.*,model=ResourceModel{id=org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.model.ResourceModel-2,name=,urlPatterns=[/],alias=/,servlet=ResourceServlet{context=/adminmodule,alias=/,name=},initParams={},context=ContextModel{id=org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.model.ContextModel-1,name=adminmodule,httpContext=org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppWebContainerContext@11710be,contextParams={webapp.context=adminmodule}}}}
[5884890@qtp-16567002-0 - /adminmodule/] DEBUG org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceContext - Handling request for [/adminmodule/] using http context [org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppWebContainerContext@11710be]
[5884890@qtp-16567002-0 - /adminmodule/] DEBUG org.mortbay.jetty - sessionManager=org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.HashSessionManager@19c6163
[5884890@qtp-16567002-0 - /adminmodule/] DEBUG org.mortbay.jetty - session=null
[5884890@qtp-16567002-0 - /adminmodule/] DEBUG org.mortbay.jetty - servlet=
[5884890@qtp-16567002-0 - /adminmodule/] DEBUG org.mortbay.jetty - chain=org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.model.FilterModel-3->
[5884890@qtp-16567002-0 - /adminmodule/] DEBUG org.mortbay.jetty - servlet holder=
[5884890@qtp-16567002-0 - /adminmodule/] DEBUG org.mortbay.jetty - call filter org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.model.FilterModel-3
[5884890@qtp-16567002-0 - /adminmodule/] DEBUG org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.WelcomeFilesFilter - Apply welcome files filter...
[5884890@qtp-16567002-0 - /adminmodule/] DEBUG org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.WelcomeFilesFilter - Servlet path: /
[5884890@qtp-16567002-0 - /adminmodule/] DEBUG org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.WelcomeFilesFilter - Path info: null
[5884890@qtp-16567002-0 - /adminmodule/] INFO org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceContext - getting resource: [/adminmodule.jsp]
[5884890@qtp-16567002-0 - /adminmodule/] DEBUG org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppWebContainerContext - Searching bundle [com.cisco.zaloni.gwt.admin [1]] for resource [/adminmodule.jsp], normalized to [adminmodule.jsp]
[5884890@qtp-16567002-0 - /adminmodule/] DEBUG org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppWebContainerContext - Resource not found
[5884890@qtp-16567002-0 - /adminmodule/] INFO org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceContext - found resource: null
[5884890@qtp-16567002-0 - /adminmodule/] DEBUG org.mortbay.jetty - call servlet 
[5884890@qtp-16567002-0 - /adminmodule/] DEBUG org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppWebContainerContext - Searching bundle [com.cisco.zaloni.gwt.admin [1]] for resource [/], normalized to [/]
[5884890@qtp-16567002-0 - /adminmodule/] DEBUG org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppWebContainerContext - Resource found as url [bundle://1.0:1/]
[5884890@qtp-16567002-0 - /adminmodule/] DEBUG org.mortbay.jetty - RESPONSE /adminmodule/  403

It is really frustrating.

please help. as I am new to OSGI.

Raul

Comment: I had a similar problem too - maybe this blog entry would be help:
http://leshazlewood.com/2010/09/08/osgi-maven-pax-and-web-applications/

Comment: @Huluvu424242 the link is dead unfortunately. I got the same issue now with more recent pax version but do not find useful information.

Comment: yes sorry. there is an copy in the internet but i don't know to trust or not.
https://blog.csdn.net/zeng_84_long/article/details/8883487
Maybe this code snippet help for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4814744/373498

Answer (score 1):

There are various bugs in pre-1.0 versions of pax-web which always tripped me up. I would suggest starting out by updating to use the latest release, pax-web 1.0.2 seems to be the latest today. If you don't want to go that high I found 0.8.1 was the first release where it really started to work properly.

Also the OSGi standard for deploying Web app bundles requires the use of the Web-ContextPath header which you did not list. This is set to the context root you want to serve the content from.

The Apache Aries project has a couple of samples that might be worth looking at to see how your bundle differs from those if this doesn't help. The Apache Aries Blog sample is documented [here](http://aries.apache.org/modules/samples/blog-sample.html) and can be downloaded from [here](http://aries.apache.org/downloads/currentrelease.html).