# Unable to deploy a Web Application Bundle on GlassFish

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, osgi, war

I'm having some serious trouble properly deploying Web Application Bundle (OSGi-fied WAR) on GlassFish server 3.1.2

When I deploy my WAR as just a web application, everything works fine and I can open my application in the browser.

But apart from that, I also want it to run in an OSGi environment. When I deploy my WAR as an OSGi bundle (using option `--type=osgi` in `asadmin deploy` command), the bundle is correctly installed into an OSGi container, but this time GlassFish doesn't recognize it as a web application - I get a 404 error (`The requested resource () is not available.`) when trying to open my app in browser.

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813819/how-to-deploy-wab-files-in-glassfish), but it doesn't work in my case.

Here's the MANIFEST of my bundle:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Webapp-Context: /ares-gui
Bundle-ClassPath: WEB-INF/classes
Bundle-Version: 0.0.0.unspecified
Tool: Bnd-1.50.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1332182568717
Bundle-Name: ares-gui
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Created-By: 1.6.0_26 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Import-Package: javax.servlet;version="[3.0,4)",javax.servlet.http;ver
 sion="[3.0,4)"
Bundle-SymbolicName: ares-gui
Web-ContextPath: /ares-gui
```

The application itself is a simple servlet annotated with a [WebServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) annotation from Servlet API 3.0.

I also tried this with other example WABs found in the net (for example [this](https://maven.java.net/service/local/repositories/releases/content/com/sun/jersey/samples/helloworld-osgi-webapp/1.12/helloworld-osgi-webapp-1.12-project.zip) one) and I get the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem in GlassFish 3.1.2 was to set `org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning` option in `glassfish3/glassfish/config/osgi.properties` configuration file to 3. I also set `glassfish.osgi.start.level.final` to 4 because I thought it should have greater value than the first option, although I'm not sure if this was needed.